# How to remove “Upcoming Events” block from the top of my facebook shop page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-timeline

It shows a block labeled "Upcoming Events" on the top of my facebook page's home. Does anyone know how to remove it and show a products slider on the top?

[image: Upcoming Events block]

Thanks!